# Can I implement interface methods as bulk operation in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have java project with 1 interface and 100 classes that implement it. If I add method to interface then I must add implementations to those 100 classes also. Does Intellij offer any bulk operation or do I have to manually open every class and implement methods? I mean yes there are keyboard shortcuts to speed this up but is there a way to do it for all classes at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, **Implement method**, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all classes, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: implement]

[image: select all]